# What is the expectation: E[(2X + 3)^2 ], given E[X] = 1?

Tags: self-study, econometrics, expected-value

I'm taking an upper level Economics class and one of my assignments asks the question in the title.

I approached it by using one property of expectation: expectation of the sum is equal to expectation of it's parts.

So, I did:

$$E[(2X + 3)^2]
= E[4X^2 + 12X + 9]
= 4E[X^2] + 12 E[X] + E[9]$$

I didn't get the right answer. I'm not even sure if what I did was the approach.

There's also second part to this question, which also asks for the variance VAR(2X + 5), given VAR(X) = 4. I can only think of one relevant property of the variance and it doesn't help with that question.

Anyone have an idea of how I should approach this?

Comment: You will need information about $E[X^2]$.  Is there anything in the original problem statement that can help you figure out that value?

Comment: Ha. @whuber corrects the maths while latexing it.

Comment: @conjugate I'm not trying to sneak in an answer via an edit: I merely corrected some typographical errors in an intermediate expression.  The distinction is important, because a true mathematical error in a question usually gives important clues concerning why the question arose and how to answer it.  Therefore, in editing a question, we should usually take care not to fix actual errors.

Comment: No accusation intended. I just chuckled. I suppose I'm less confident than you about my ability distinguishing the essential from the non-essential errors in understanding. (So I tend not to, though have no problem with others doing it).  Actually, given the holistic nature of beginners understanding, I'm not totally confident of the distinction at all. As always, the proof is in the OP enlightenment.

Comment: @whuber There wasn't anything else included with the original problem except that, I checked. Though, I'm not sure if that was a genuine question or if you're asking me to think it through a bit more. I originally thought that E[X^2} for this problem would also be 1. I'll look though my notes for anything that might help me figure out what E[X^2] could be.

Comment: @whuber Well, I tried to rearrange the problem to make it (2E[X] + 3)^2. It doesn't make much a difference, my answer is still 25. I'm not sure if I've had the right answer all along, since sometimes, the given answers to the homework have been wrong (since it's multiple choice.)

Comment: Is  $X$ the same variable in part 1 and 2?

Comment: I think they are the same. Either way, I ended up using property Var (aX+B) = a^2 Var(x) and got an answer that matches the choices he gave me.

Comment: "I originally thought that E[X^2} for this problem would also be 1"  No, except in degenerate cases (when $X$ is a constant), $E[X^2] \gt (E[X])^2$. The _difference_ $E[X^2] - (E[X])^2$ is the _variance_ of $X$. But to repeat whuber's question with slightly different wording "Are you sure you are not told _anything_ else about $X$"? For example, you might not be sharing with us that the information that $X$ is an _exponential_ random variable on the grounds that it is irrelevant, but it really _is_ a very relevant fact. For an exponential random variable with $E[X]=1$, $E[X^2]$ equals $2$.

Comment: @DilipSarwate We've only been dealing with standard normal random variables, there's been no mention of exponential random variables. I wish I could say I had more information than that, but I've looked through everything in the assignment and that's all that was given. 

The possible answers he gave were (a) 11 (b) 21 (c) 31 (d) 41.

Comment: No, it never explicitly mentioned in that specific problem that X was a standard normal variable. It's just come up on a few problems that we've been working on lately, and usually the question would state it clearly that X was a standard normal random variable.

Comment: If we don't assume the variance in part 2 is connected to the Q in part 1, about all we can do is say that the expectation is $25+4\text{Var}(X)$, so the expectation must be at least $25$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the comments, I assume the that the $X$ in part 1 and 2 is the same. Then we know $\mathbb E X =1,\mathrm{Var}(X)=4$.

You may now find the answer by using the relationship $\mathrm{Var}(X)=\mathbb EX^2- (\mathbb E X)^2$.
(**Hint**: The correct answer is 41.)

*I leave the below as an example of why the information in the first part is not sufficient.*

Let $Y=1$, $X\sim N(1,1)$. Then $\mathbb E (2Y+3)^2=25$ while $(2X+3)=:Z\sim N(5, 4)$ so that $\mathbb E Z^2 = \mathrm{Var}(Z)+(\mathbb E Z)^2=29$.

Comment: X looks to be the same variable in part 1/2, and before I read your comment I ended up getting 16 as an answer after realizing that Var (aX+B) = a^2 Var(X). I think that's the same as Var(X)= E[X]^2- (EX)^2?  

Would I also be wrong in getting 25 for the answer in the first part? The professor might have made a typo in the answer choices he gave us, which has happened a lot before.

Comment: Re: "Var (aX+B) = a^2 Var(X). I think that's the same as Var(X)= E[X]^2- (EX)^2?"

No, they're not the same formula. 

25 is not the correct answer for the first question. Have you tried using the formula I gave for the variance together with the given fact $Var(X)=4$ on the expression you have derived in your question?

Comment: You're right, I misread the notes and the formulas aren't the same. Yes, I thought it over some more and from what you gave me, I realized that E[X]^2 = 5. Would that be wrong? If I plug that into part 1 and I get 41, which is D from the answer choices.

Comment: You are correct!

Comment: Whoop whoop! I never thought of that formula before, or at least it was never given to me explicitly. Either way, it's great to know. Oh, was I wrong for part 2 as well? I thought I had the right property for that one.

Comment: Your formula is correct for part 2